# Google analytics API with a service account wrongfully Quota Error

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client, service-accounts

tl;dr: I'm getting `Quota Error: You have exceeded the maximum number of writes/day for this project` even tho I have 50k queries / day as the quota limit.

I have a project on [google cloud consle](https://console.cloud.google.com/) with GA API enabled:

[image]

Oddly enough, in the GA Quotas view I see two anonymous Query sections, both with 50k queries / day: (deleted the graphs to capture both quotas on same screen)

[image]

A side question here, why do I have two Query sections? what does each mean?

I have a service account with access to this project:

[image]

with a generated JSON key:

[image]

and I'm using that service account to make API requests:

```
const path = require('path')
const { google } = require('googleapis')

module.exports = createApiInstance

const keyFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../credentials.json')

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: keyFilePath,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'],
})

auth.getClient().then(client => {
  client.request(params)
})
```

I can get away with just a few requests in a day before I run into the quota limit error.

One weird thing is that even tho I just made some requests a few minutes ago, the service account's logs come up empty:

[image]

Which would be tempting to say the service account isn't being used, but, if that was the case how would I be able to get away with the few requests that do actually pass?

I'm not using any Auth'ing other than the service account generated credentials file ‍♀️

As an aside, we are using the same service account with the same credentials file on another project for a different google API, and it works as expected.

any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

First off do not go by what you are seeing in the google developer console.

1. The report does not display write requests only total requests.
2. Default write request quota is **50** not 50000
3. that is not Realtime report
4. its a estimate it is not 100% correct
5. not all apis write to the service account logs.
6. this is a project based quota so if you have any other methods writing then they are in the same total.

If the error message says you are going over the limit you are going over the limit. Just apply for an extension.  This is one of the easer apis to get an extension on.

[Limits and Quotas on API Requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas)
[image]

You have to go over to https://console.cloud.google.com/ to see what your writes per day are

[image]

Comment: on the quotas screen I have two sections without names (see images), both set to 50k/day, but I don't see a differentiation between read and write, and on the docs it says the initial limit is 50/day. I don't see a way to view the write quotas of a project

Comment: The report does not display write requests there is no way of seeing how many write requests you have sent.   You just have to go by the error message.

Comment: I'm asking how can I see my write requests limit for a project?

Comment: Check the last picture it shows you my limit is 600 per minute.  But this only shows if you are using the google analtyics admin api.  If you are using the normal google analytics api there is no way to see what your current limit is to extend it [check](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#additional_quota)